# Actual link style doesn't match preview link style

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[I'll add a link to Stack Overflow to demonstrate here, then you can click to edit this post.](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

For those that are a bit less hands-on, here's a screenshot from an earlier answer I created, with the unvisited link on top, and the visited link on the bottom.

[image]

From what I can tell, the `.post-text` class isn't used anywhere in the preview area.  Perhaps it should be; it is a *preview* of the actual post, after all.

Comment: I've been wanting to post this but have been putting it off. I definitely think the underlining should be in the preview as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this on dev. It will go out on live after our next production build.

Comment: Looks like this may be broken again at least on SO? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350147/so-links-do-not-render-like-they-do-in-the-editor-preview