# SO links do not render like they do in the editor preview

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor, markdown-rendering

**Duplicate of [Editor preview resolves title to HTTP links but rendered post does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296628/230261)**

---

It looks like this was fixed once, here: [Actual link style doesn't match preview link style](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286324/actual-link-style-doesnt-match-preview-link-style)

See this question: [How to disable page scroll while dragging draggable in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395936/how-to-disable-page-scroll-while-dragging-draggable-in-jquery)

Here is what it looks like in edit mode with preview:

[image]

And here is how it renders after saving:

[image]

Oddly, as you see from the links above, it seems to work fine on meta.stackoverflow.com...

Comment: It's HTTP links; reported on MSE a few days ago: [Editor preview resolves title to HTTP links but rendered post does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296628/230261)

Comment: Also noted here, albeit specifically about wiki edits: [Tag wiki preview looks ok, live changes look crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349579/tag-wiki-preview-looks-ok-live-changes-look-crap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a artifact of the change to HTTPS.  If you edit the link to the question to be

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily
```

It renders correctly

[image]

Comment: I saw your edit.  Good catch.  Should probably still be fixed though, right? <del>At least to be consistent with meta?</del>

Comment: @RatherNotsay IIRC they are supposed to be going though all the posts and updating the links to HTTPS.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Also, if you check your question, you'll see your links are using HTTPS.  If you change then to HTTP, you get the same behavior.