# URL rendering bug in answer editor

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor, markdown-rendering

Reproduce by clicking the edit link under https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326205/2943403.
Notice that in the rendered view of my answer, the link to another SO answer is a clickable hyperlink, but after saving or cancelling the edit, the url is plain text / not clickable.

Before edit:

> [image]

After edit:

> [image]

[The only related meta page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350147/2943403) that I could find for this was several years old, so I assume this is a new bug with the new editor.